# python alias on mac showing bash error

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, applescript, alias

hello respected persons ,

i am working on mac and trying to creating a alias on mac but alias work until i close current terminal after when i put alias in new terminal its shows bash error my code is

```
alias macd='python /Users/exepaul/Desktop/mac.py'
```

and when i put macd in current open terminal it works but when i put macd in new terminal its shows this error

```
MacBook-Air:~ exepaul$ macd
-bash: macd: command not found
```

please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your aliases to your `.bashrc` so it will be automatically available when you start a new login or non-login shell.

Comment: how i can add aliases to my .bashrc ??

Comment: @exepaul edit your file using (for example) `vim ~/.bashrc`, move the cursor at the end and add your alias.

Comment: Technically, `.bashrc` will not be executed for login shells, unless you are doing so explicitly from the login shell's configuration file.

Comment: @chepner, you're 100% right however is quite common to find `.bashrc` sourced" by `.bash_profile`